# Can't get url for both images with rails and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have installed paperclip in my rails application, everything works fine but the problem is that I added two images for my Customer entity and when I return a Customer in the front-end (through API call) side I only get 1 url.
This is the code:

Console log of the Customer entity:

```
Object {id: 2,
name: "carlos",
surname: "ruiz",
email: "carlos@car.com",
password_digest:"$2a$10$pJnjlXk5YUq0YrD5WhtmB.nDL3oeKo2U6S9JKSjhbfWf5ti6Ex6k2"…}
created_at: "2016-02-10T18:52:11.000Z"
email: "carlos@car.com"
header_path_content_type: "image/png"
header_path_file_name: "clients.png"
header_path_file_size: 1445943
header_path_updated_at: "2016-03-11T11:49:58.000Z"
image_path: "/system/customers/image_paths/000/000/002/original/earnings.png?1457696996"
image_path_content_type: "image/png"
image_path_file_name: "earnings.png"
image_path_file_size: 1587885
image_path_updated_at: "2016-03-11T11:49:56.000Z"
```

As you can see I have the image_path path: /system/customers/... but I don't have the header_path path, just the content, the file size, name and date.

Here is the model:

```
  class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_attached_file :image_path, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/user_images/missing.png"
    has_attached_file :header_path, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/user_headers/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image_path, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    validates_attachment_content_type :header_path, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  end
```

Migration:

```
class AddUserPhoto < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    add_attachment :customers, :image_path
    add_attachment :customers, :header_path
  end

  def down
    remove_attachment :customers, :image_path
    remove_attachment :customers, :header_path
  end
end
```

The strange thing is that in the console and in the back-end admin part I can upload and see both images, and if I type Customer.first.header_path in the console I can see the correct path. But when I send the Customer through the api I have this problem.
Here is the function that return the customer:

```
  def client_details
    hairdresser_id =  params[:api][:hairdresser_id]
    token =           params[:api][:token]
    customer_id =     params[:api][:customer_id]

    if token.nil? or token.empty?
      render :json => {:error => "not authorized"}
    end

    if allowed_customers_id.include? customer_id.to_i
      customer = Customer.find customer_id

      render :json => {
        :customer_details => customer,
        :customer_addresses => customer.addresses,
        :customer_note => note,
        :customer_appointments => Appointment.where(:customer_id => customer.id).reverse,
        :appointment_services => Appointment.where(:customer_id => customer.id).where.not(:status => 'cancelled').map{|app| app.service_appointments.first.service.name}.reverse,
        :error => ''
      }
    else
      render :json => {:error => 'Not authorized'}
    end
  end
```

Do you know what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure `image_path` is a real attribute and not a result of a method ? I think both `image_path` and `header_path` are methods. By default, only object attributes are serialized in JSON.

Comment: You are right, I solve the problem returning in the json file Customer.header_path.url(:medium)!

Thanks!